# How to compare each element in one structured list with time complexity less than O(n^2) in java

Tags: java, algorithm

Suppose I have a structured List Like `List<Data>` and my Data class is :

```
class Data {
   int Id;
   int duration;  
}
```

My List has about 10 million records.

My elements are unique but it is possible for two elements to have same id.

1. How can I fetch elements with same id that have duration difference?
2. Which algorithm has less time complexity to return my required elements?

Comment: I'd sort the list by id first which is `O(n*log(n))`, then iterate and look for duplicates which is `O(n)` so the complexity is still `O(n*log(n))`. If you need the original list to be unchanged, create a copy first which is another `O(n)` but doesn't change overall complexity (in the end it would be `O(n * (log(n) + 2))` which is `O(n * log(n))`.

Comment: Or use a different data structure that has more suitable performance characteristics.  [Possible example](https://java-programming.mooc.fi/part-8/4-grouping-data-using-hash-maps).

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, that might be even better if space is not an issue. Create a hashmap that has enough space, insert the data and then iterate and look for those that have duplicates. That should get it to basically `O(n)` time complexity at the cost of some memory.

Comment: @Thomas Well, if you already have a key for your group, it's going to be O(1) for the key.

Comment: `HashMap<int, list<int>>`

Comment: @RobertHarvey that's true but from the question I assume the OP is interested in all keys (which I assume would be "id"). Plus the map would have to be built from the list (which I assumed as a given) so this would still be O(n).

Comment: Hmm, maybe maintain two Hash Maps, one with individual ids, another with duplicate ids.  Determining if an ID has a duplicate is then O(1).

Comment: @Thomas If space is an issue, an initial pass with a Bloom filter could eliminate all but the duplicates and a few false positives, which would then need to be checked.

Comment: yeah that was great it fetched required Ids in less than 2 seconds!